# How can I determine valid Mac OS X Server `serveradmin` commands?

Tags: command-line-interface, mac-osx-server, command

I've used Mac OS X Server's `serveradmin` command line interface for Server Admin.app & now Server.app for starting & stopping services, viewing status & settings, and occasionally running what few commands I can find documented on random blogs. There's a lot more that I'd like to do with it, but I can't seem to find a good reference for available commands (e.g. `serveradmin command <service>:command = <...>`).

The manpage has only a couple examples and, as previously mentioned, I've found a few on various Mac admin blogs, but nothing comprehensive and no mention of how to discover more. Is there a command that will list commands? Are people decompiling the binary and looking for command strings? Or, are people just using what precious few commands have been mentioned by Apple support & engineers?

Comment: Not an answer, but hope it helps:  https://www.apple.com/server/docs/Command_Line.pdf - search "serveradmin" there and "next" through it for examples of various usage scenarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used OSX Server in over a year, but I remember that it was possible to get a command list with `serveradmin --help` or something like that. Also, at least for 10.6 server (the last *real* version) and previous, they had a [whole book](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=answerlink&url=http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/IntroCommandLine_v10.6.pdf&answerid=16777220&src=support_site.manuals.search) on command line administration in their documentation section.

Comment: @TheCleaner Apple's Command Line Administration book does contain short lists of available `serveradmin` commands for each service. Thanks!